# jQuery sortable table cells html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a table that displays a daily program, lets assume that it looks like this:

```js
var td = "anything";
$( function() {
  $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
    items: td
  });
  $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table" id="sortable" >
  <tr>
    <th>item1</th>
    <th>item2</th>
    <th>item3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>content1</td>
    <td>content2</td>
    <td>content3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>content4</td>
    <td>content5</td>
    <td>content6</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

i want to make the "td" of my table to be sortable so i can swap the contents in it by dragging them.

I initially saw this
  http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#default
and then i wanted to make it work for a table.

I also have a question: Will it appear a problem (on sortable functioning), if I use ajax on html to get that (sortable) table from an asp page? Because, that's what I actually want to make. I tried to make it simple for you to understand what I want. Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Take a look at the jQuery DataTables plugin.  It does this and many other things very well.

Comment: what is the value td supposed to be

Comment: @TheValyreanGroup thanks for the information thats another plug in that i would like to insert also but its not quite much what i was looking for.
"I initially saw this http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#default and then i wanted to make it work for a table"
take a look at this link please.

Comment: @PhilipKirkbride anything.